# Auto transmission just stopped working while I was driving

Tags: automatic-transmission, troubleshooting, mitsubishi

While I was driving, my cars automatic transmission suddenly would not work in drive or reverse but the motor was still running.

Does someone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you checked the level of your automatic transmission fluid?

Comment: How many miles are on this vehicle?

Comment: Yes plenty of oil! However I had not done service for 8 moths as I was in Hospital and simply forgot.

Comment: So oil and Automatic transmission fluid are different.  You have two dipsticks.  One for each.

Comment: Did you manage to get your car going again?